# I created a calendar that asks for a month and year. I wanted to modify it so that it asks the user for only a year and prints out all the months

Tags: java, calendar, output, user-input

I am a beginner coder and I have some experience with Java.

I made this simple calendar program and kept changing it in the past week. I wanted to make it so that a perfect series of dates would appear when a user inputs a  month and a year. However, I wanted to change it so that the user only asks for a year and the entire sets of months are shown.

For example the code asks to enter a year: . The user must choose any year they want, (I already took care of the leap year issue), and all months from January to December must show up in order and in correct format. I tried to change my code but I keep messing up. How would I go the best way to change my code so that I can get the entire set of months in a year given by a user?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Month
{
    private static final String[] MONTHS = {
            "", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
            "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
        };

    private static final int[] NUMDAYS = {
            0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
        };

    private int month;
    private int year;

    public Month(int month, int year) {
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    private boolean isLeapYear() {
        if(year % 400 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if(year % 100 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return year % 4 == 0;
    }

    private int getNumDays() {
        if(month == 2) {
            if(isLeapYear()) {
                return 29;
            }
            else {
                return 28;
            }
        }
        else {
            return NUMDAYS[month];
        }
    }

    private int getStartDOW() {
        int m, y;
        if(month < 3) {
            m = month + 12;
            y = year - 1;
        }
        else {
            m = month;
            y = year;
        }
        return (13 * (m + 1) / 5 + y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400) % 7;
    }

    public void printCalendar() {
        //I changed this part so that the month and year could be centered, if you have an 
        //easier or cleaner way to do it, I would appreciate learning it.

        if(month == 2||month == 11 || month == 12 || month == 9){
            System.out.println("    " + MONTHS[month] + " " + year);
        }else if(month == 3||month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 7 || month == 5){
            System.out.println("      " + MONTHS[month] + " " + year);
        }else if(month == 1||month == 10 || month == 8){

            //This is what I originally had System.out.println("    " + MONTHS[month] + " " 
            //+ year);
        }
        System.out.println(" S  M  T  W  T  F  S");
        int dow = getStartDOW();
        for(int i = 0; i < dow; i++) {
            System.out.print("   ");
        }
        int numdays = getNumDays();
        for(int i = 1; i <= numdays; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%2d ", i);
            if(dow == 6) {
                System.out.println();
                dow = 0;
            }
            else {
                dow++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter month (1-12)");
        int month = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter year: ");
        int year = s.nextInt();
        Month m = new Month(month, year);
        m.printCalendar();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry about the formatting issues.

Comment: Since you mentioned already taking care of new year, it's relevant to read this if you're working with time and dates: https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca  It's so complicated that the original Java utilities for working with time and dates had a lot of problems, and they eventually added the `java.time` package to the standard library to fix all the issues. This is not a trivial issue at all. Personally, I wouldn't attempt coding it myself from scratch as an exercise, because it sounds like torture. I'd just use the `java.time` package.

Comment: Also, your code is Java and has nothing to do with Javascript.

Comment: I fixed your formatting. But you can learn to do so yourself: Either indent all lines by four spaces OR wrap in a pair of triple back-ticks.

Comment: If doing schoolwork, **say so**. Our answers will vary accordingly. In this case, if you were doing real work we would replace all your code to use instead the built-in *java.time* classes.

Comment: You are sure that you want to solve the problem yourself and not rely on mature library methods of Java? Also which Java version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a function that takes month and year and renders that month.

How about you create another function that has just the year as parameter, then loops over all months and calls the function that needs month and year as parameters. It also assembles the rendered months into a year calendar.